# Why do I get the error "Unmatched ( in regex" when trying to match something with Net::Telnet?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to match the string

```
Save settings:([Y]/[N]):
```

that the telnet client returns after issuing

```
print("exit")
```

(I'm using `Net::Telnet`.)

I have tried several regexes, including this one:

```
waitfor(“/^\s+ Save settings:([Y]/[N]):\s$/”
```

but I continue to receive the error:

```
bad match operator: Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\s+Save settings?( <-- HERE [Y]/ <$data> line 1. at printer_config_test.pl line 36
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seeing your regex would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You are providing the following regex match operator:

```
/^s+ Save settings:([Y]/   (followed by junk)
```

---

If you want to match the following string:

```
Save settings:([Y]/[N]):
```

You want the following regex pattern:

```
^\s*Save settings:\(\[Y\]/\[N\]\):
```

But `waitfor` wants a string containing a match operator. The following is the desired match operator:

```
/^\s*Save settings:\(\[Y\]\/\[N\]\):/
```

And the following is a string literal to that creates that string:

```
"/^\\s*Save settings:\\(\\[Y\\]\\/\\[N\\]\\):/"
```

So:

```
waitfor("/^\\s*Save settings:\\(\\[Y\\]\\/\\[N\\]\\):/")
```

Comment: (Net::Telnet should have accepted a regex pattern rather than a match operator!)